calling a function with world_lstener in keyboard python library
i am trying to make a python program using the keyboard library to let the user generate a random number when he types ";rand a,b;" where the program detects if ;rand is typed to lunch a function where it listens for every input and register it in a variable
it waits for the user to enter numbers or "," to know the limits of the generator
when the user press ";" again it lunches the random generator
everything is working fine until when you retype the ";rand" again after finishing
it seems to  calling the same function multiple times because when you press like 5 it reads it twice and insert 55 in the variable
here is the code:
if random_option: #just to check if the user turned this option or not
     random_display = ""
     print("now you can use ;rand")
     keyboard.add_word_listener(";rand",lambda:start())
     def stop_random():
        global random_work
        print("now you can use ;rand")
        random_work = False
     def start():
        if not random_work:
            return
        print("listening for random")
        keyboard.on_press(rand)
     def rand(key):
        global random_display
        if random_work:
            for i in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",",","-","!"]:
                if keyboard.is_pressed(i):
                    random_display+=i
                    print(random_display)
                    break
                elif keyboard.is_pressed("backspace"):
                    random_display = random_display[:len(random_display)-1]
                    print(random_display)
                    break
                elif keyboard.is_pressed("space") or keyboard.is_pressed("shift") or keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
                    break
                elif keyboard.is_pressed(";"):
                    try:
                        print("calculating and exising")
                        p = random_display.find(",")
                        a = int(random_display[:p])
                        b = int(random_display[p+1:])
                        if a>b:
                            a,b = b,a
                        result = str(random.randint(a,b))
                        keyboard.write("=")
                        keyboard.write(result)
                        random_display = ""
                        stop_random()
                        break
                    except:
                        print("failed and we will leave")
                        random_display=""
                        stop_random()
                        break
                elif i == "!":
                    print("cleaning")
                    random_display = ""
                    stop_random()

i tried to remove_world_listener and readd it later when it finishes but nothing works

After you've detected that a key is pressed, you need to wait until that key is no longer pressed before checking again.  The way you currently have it, all keys have instant auto-repeat.
